# Problema con footer

Tags: html, css

He intentado todo lo que he podido para conseguir que mi pie este bottom : 0 pero nada , se queda a 20%- 30% de esto.

aqui el código

```
  body ,html{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }


  footer{
   left: 0;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #4ABDAC;
   bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
```

el padre del footer es el body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías probar con:

```
* {
padding:0; 
margin:0;
} 

footer{
   left: 0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #4ABDAC;
 }
```

Comment: mejora, pero sigue quedando un espacio al final de la pagina

Comment: Vale entonces prueba añadir esto a tu archivo css, * {padding:0; margin:0;}

Comment: https://imgur.com/9ahBcWO lo subi a imgur para que lo veas.

Comment: Funciona! , si quieres postea la respuesta y te la pongo como valida.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta entonces, gracias.